# how to Run socket and ui updation simultaneously without interruption

Tags: android

I have to receive an image via socket and display it in a ImageView .
But after ui updation socket get disconnected .For ui updation i use Handler ,i also tried Asynctask. socket running in Thread.
How to remain connected to socket while updating ui simultaneously

Comment: Good approach. And what was your question again?

Answer (score 0):

The image updating should be done via [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            if (isrunning) {
                     _tts.speak(num,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
       }
   });
```

If you post some code, I could update the answer.